# how to use mock in webdriverIO to send response as string

Tags: webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I have a POST API that returns the response as a string.

when I tried mocking as `browser.mock('**/validate').respond('SUCCESS', { statusCode: 200 });`

It's not getting mocked instead original API is hit

Can someone help me in this??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using WireMock Service?

More info: https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-wiremock-service/